# Java Stream equivalent of LINQ SelectMany()

Tags: java, linq, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

What's the [Java 8 Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) equivalent of LINQ's [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx)?

For example, in C#, if I have `Dictionary<string, List<Tag>> tags` that I want to turn into an `IEnumerable<Tag>` (a flat enumerable of all the tags in the dictionary), I would do `tags.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value)`.

Is there a Java equivalent for a `Map<String, List<Tag>>` that would yield a `Stream<Tag>`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're looking to [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) all the values contained in the map:

```
Map<String, List<Tag>> map = new HashMap<>();
Stream<Tag> stream = map.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream);
```

This code first retrieves all the values of the map as a `Collection<List<Tag>>` with [`values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--), creates a Stream out of this collection with [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--), and then flat maps each `List<Tag>` into a `Stream` with the method reference `List::stream`.

Comment: @RobertFraser They're not to be confused

Comment: @RobertFraser The name comes from the [map function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29) which "maps a function" over (a list of) values.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for simple SelectMany:

```
tags.stream().map(x -> x.Values).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```